# How do I get an array to another function so I can display it into another div

Tags: javascript

I have this text file I am reading... I read it into an array.

`fields[0]` is the term, `fields[1]` is the definition and `fields[2]` is the example.

I am trying to pass the array I get from the text file into another function so I can display the definition and example in another `<div>`. Here is my code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
     <!--<input type="file" id="fileinput" /> -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function allText()
         {
             if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
             {
                 var inputText = xmlhttp.responseText;  // the whole text file being stored in a variable
                 var lines = inputText.split('\n');  // splitting the whole file into manageable rows using \n
                 var allMainText = "";  // declaring a variable for use later
                 for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) // creating a for loop
                 {
                     var fields = lines[i].split('||');  // this is where the separation between tag, definition and example happens
                     // fields 0 is the tag itself
                     // fields 1 is the definition
                     // fields 2 is the example
                     var oneLine = '<a href = "#' + fields[0]
                                 + ' "   onclick="testFunction();"> '
                                 + '&lt;' 
                                 + fields[0]
                                 + '&gt;'
                                 + ' </a> ||';
                     allMainText += oneLine;  // += means that things can be added as the loop executes
                 }
                 document.getElementById("menu").innerHTML = allMainText;  // allMainText is displayed in the "main" div
             }
         }

         function testFunction (fields, oneLine)
         {
             var defandExample = fields[1] + '<br/>' + fields[2]; 
             document.getElementById("defandexample").innerHTML = defandExample;
         }

         xmlhttp.open("GET", "everythingtext.txt", true);  // getting the actual .txt file to be used
         xmlhttp.send();
     </script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/everythinghtmldynamize.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu"> yo </div>
    <div id="defandexample"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the variables "fields" and "oneLine" global scope by declaring them right after you declare the "xmlhttp" variable.